# Using the EMA'ed weights for evaluation in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow's tutorial it says that there are two ways to use the EMA'ed weights for evaluation

1. Build a model that uses the shadow variables instead of the
   variables. For this, use the `average()` method which returns the
   shadow variable for a given variable.
2. Build a model normally but load the checkpoint files to evaluate by
   using the shadow variable names. For this use the `average_name()`
   method. See the Saver class for more information on restoring saved
   variables.

I understand how to use the second method to use the EMA'ed weights for evaluation as an example is given. I was wondering if someone could give me a simple example of how to build a model that uses the shadow variables.